# SSISDB - Package For Each Enumerator Is Empty

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package that works perfectly fine in my Visual Studio, it works perfectly fine when launched via SQL Agent and I have an external program (VisualCron) that can run the individual DTSX package fine.

However I have deployed the very same package to my Integration Services Catalog on my new SQL Server and when executing the job, it completes successfully however the For Each Enumerator Task does not see the file that is available to process.

This File Enumerator is a UNC Path "//IP Address/Folder/" and the File Name is a Wildcard *XYZ_ABC*.csv.

The package works perfectly fine everywhere else, can someone please explain to me why the package when executed via SSISDB it cannot see the files. The permission on the directory is 'EVERYBODY' I have also tried to change the filename in the For Each to be SPECIFICALLY the filename available again it still doesn't work, the log in SSISDB tells me the For Each File Enumerator is empty.

UPDATE -  Picture:

[image: Error Message]

Any and all advice is appreciated.

Comment: The permissions may be correct if you have everyone, but the server may not have access to that path from the server itself.  I would check your error trapping to ensure it captures the errors properly as well so you can properly debug because if it is permissions or can not find path issue you should be getting an error.

Comment: @Brad - There isn't any error trapping at this point because it isn't an error, its a warning stating the file doesn't exist in the path. If it was a permissions issue then it would state that access is denied.

Comment: Similr to Brad's comment - Can you ask one of your DBAs to log on to the SQL Server using the SQL Server Service account and get them to try and open the UNC path. At least you will be sure that this isn't the issue. Also is this a hardcoded value, a Configured value, or is it being built from an expression? - I'd try and log the value just before the Enumerator runs just to make sure its what you think it is...

Comment: @johnMcTighe The path is accessible from the SQL Server via the same account that runs the SQL Agent Service. I have just tested the UNC path also. The address is a hardcoded UNC path in the SSIS package. If I change the path to a drive directly on the SQL Server it works. However the UNC path to the 'off-server' location doesn't work, I have tried changing the service account for the SQL Agent Service as well and testing and get the same issue again. It would help if I knew what account was trying to run the SSISDB package. I assume it is the Agent Service Account.

Comment: It might be using a Proxy Account - If you can see the Job Step then look to see what is in the "Run As" option. (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysproxies might help...)

Comment: @johnMcTighe thanks for the reply, the table for sysproxies is empty. I am logged on as myself, the package will complain of access denied when logged on with my domain account, it works fine from the server directly by doing right click execute, however it neither works from VisualCron that proxies the Administrator account to run it complaining of access is denied and also fails as the job which is ran with the administrator account.

Comment: Hmm - One thing I find with folder permissions is that you have to grant access to the share folder and then to all sub-folders - It doesn't always ripple up. so if you have //192.168.1.1/share/filefolder/myfile.csv then even though everyone has access to the file - you still need to explicitly grant access to the share folder (and sub folders)